# how to print all the values of pointers of pointers of char in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I have these code:

```
unsigned char **keys;
int *num_keys;

int num_images = (int) key_files.size(); // the result is 10 for example

keys = new unsigned char *[num_images];
num_keys = new int[num_images];

/* Read all keys */
for (int i = 0; i < num_images; i++) {
    keys[i] = NULL;
    num_keys[i] = ReadKeyFile(key_files[i].c_str(), keys+i);
}
```

I would like to read back using printf all of the elements inside keys, how can I do it?

I am just starting with C++, pointers make me not comfortable.

For other language, I think it should be an array of 2 dimensions: array[a][b] then I can loop it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
  for(int i=j; j<b; j++)
     printf(array[i][j]);
```

I think something like that, unless the char **keys has another meaning? and how can I print all of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an absolutely terrible approach. Please forget everything anyone may have told you over a beer about pointers, and start by learning idiomatic, modern C++. The standard library has containers that allow you to write this code in a much more readable, and moreover *correct* and *safe* fashion.

Comment: So let's review... You store key file names in an array of std::string which key_files apparently is, and store the content of those files in char** ?? Not that it's not a valid c++ but I strongly advise you to be consistent and store your keys in a (static/dynamic/array/list) of std::string as well, e.g typedef vector<string> KeyVec etc.

Comment: that is an original implementation, I am trying read the num_keys back and put them in two arrays of float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, your program could be written like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//...

const unsigned int num_images = key_file.size();

std::vector<unsigned char *> keys(num_images);
std::vector<int>         num_keys(num_images);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != num_images; ++i)
{
  num_keys[i] = ReadKeyFile(key_files[i].c_str(), &keys[i]);

  // if the key is a null-terminated string:
  std::cout << "The key[" << i << "] is: '" << keys[i] << "'." << std::endl;

  // if the key is just a bunch of bytes, num_keys[i] in number:
  for (int j = 0; j != num_keys[i]; ++j)
  {
    std::cout << "key[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << (unsigned int)(keys[i][j]) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I put the printing in the same loop that does the reading; you could also do the printing in a separate loop if you preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that array has type char **. You can do this with

`printf("%c", array[i][j])`

Here `"%c"` is acting as a format string telling it to expect a char from the next argument.